# upload sdcard docs to Google Drive in android

Tags: android, google-drive-api

From my application, I want to upload sdcard documents to google drive for a particular Gmail account.

I referred this documentation on [google drive](https://developers.google.com/drive/get-started) . But I don't understand how to do that.
Please help me, Thanks in advance

Comment: Will the user have the Google Drive application installed?

Comment: @Praveena_Pinki I need help to integrate Google drive on Android app to share file, please guide with sample.

Answer (score 1):

I would start here [Google API for java](https://developers.google.com/drive/downloads)

Download the API and explore the documentation on how to use it.  The link also provides code samples you should be able to try out and experiment with.  From what I've discovered in a few minutes, you first need to get authorization using OAuth 2.0

Then it's just a matter using Drive.Files.insert()  (which is apparently a JSON PUT)
The API also allows other functionality, like listing documents, copying, deleting, etc.